# declaring variable inside while loop javascript

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop, scope

I don't understand this code.

```
var timesTable;
while ((timesTable = prompt("Enter the times table", -1)) != -1) {.....}
```

Why is necessary to declare the variable before? I tried to do this:

```
while ((var timesTable = prompt("Enter the times table", -1)) != -1) {.....}
```

but it doesn't work. What's the problem? Is something about scope?

The full program is:

```
function writeTimesTable(timesTable, timesByStart, timesByEnd) {
        for (; timesByStart <= timesByEnd; timesByStart++) {
            document.write(timesTable + " * " + timesByStart + " = " + timesByStart * timesTable + "<br />");
            }
        }
    var timesTable;
    while ((timesTable = prompt("Enter the times table", -1)) != -1) {
        while (isNaN(timesTable) == true) {
            timesTable = prompt(timesTable + " is not a " + "valid number, please retry", -1);
        }
        document.write("<br />The " + timesTable + " times table<br />");
        writeTimesTable(timesTable, 1, 12);
    }
```

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't define a variable within a `while` loop, there is no such construct in javascript;

[image]

The reason that you *can* define it within a `for` loop is because a for loop has an initialization construct defined.

```
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) { ... }
//     |           |     |
// initialisation  |     |
//            condition  |
//                    execute after each loop
```

Basically, it won't work because it is invalid code.

You can however remove the `var` declaration completely, but that will essentially make the variable `global` and is considered bad practice.

That is the reason you are seeing the `var` declaration directly above the `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

This is the best alternative I could come up with

```
for (let i = 0; i < Number.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
  const variable = getVariable(i);
  if (/* some condition */) { break; }
  /* logic for current iteration */
}
```